# iOS 13 - How to check if user has accepted Bluetooth permission?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

As part of iOS 13’s, apps now need to request permission if they want to access Bluetooth.
[image]

How to check if user has accepted Bluetooth permission?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`CBCentralManager`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager?changes=latest_minor) extends [`CBManager`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbmanager?changes=latest_minor). As of iOS 13, `CBManager` has an [`authorization`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbmanager/3180033-authorization?changes=latest_minor) property.

Use this property to determine whether permission is unknown, allowed, denied, or restricted.

To be clear, under iOS, you need to use the instance property `authorization`, not the type property of the same name. Be sure you access `authorization` on an instance of `CBCentralManager`.

Comment: Could you please post a coding example? I've trying to use authorization property without any success. Thank you!

Comment: @Franlon Please post your own question with all relevant details and code.

Answer (score 31):

Try this:

```swift
var isBluetoothPermissionGranted: Bool {
    if #available(iOS 13.1, *) {
        return CBCentralManager.authorization == .allowedAlways
    } else if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        return CBCentralManager().authorization == .allowedAlways
    }
    
    // Before iOS 13, Bluetooth permissions are not required
    return true
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the best / most correct answer for a Central side connection (the most common case), since it touches on only the central manager, and handles both 13.0 and 13.1+ API.

Comment: WARNING: this will cause a alert on ios13.0 to keeping ask user to authorize app ble permission. Using CBCentralManager(delegate,queue,options) instead，and set the CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey to false.

Comment: This may have worked, but seems dubious since it is potentially accessing both the central and peripheral managers, which are on opposite sides of the connection. Beyond that, the 13.0 solution has been deprecated in 13.1

Comment: did this become incorrect? This is returning true even when the user hasn't granted permissions yet.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 5** **IOS 13**:  *based of accepted answer, but handles the peripheral connection type as well*:

```swift
    enum BluetoothConnectionType {
        case central, peripheral
    }

    func isBluetoothAuthorized(forType type: BluetoothConnectionType) -> Bool {
        switch type {
        case .central:
            if #available(iOS 13.1, *) { return CBCentralManager.authorization == .allowedAlways }
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) { return CBCentralManager().authorization == .allowedAlways }
            return true
        case .peripheral:
            if #available(iOS 13.1, *) { return CBPeripheralManager.authorization == .allowedAlways }
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) { return CBPeripheralManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorized }
            return true
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not specific to Swift 5. This code works as-is in Swift 4 and 4.2 as well.

Comment: This may have worked, but seems dubious since it is potentially accessing both the central and peripheral managers, which are on opposite sides of the connection. Beyond that, the 13.0 solution has been deprecated in 13.1.  See @al_mota's answer for the currently correct method.

Answer (score 8):

It's interesting that starting `iOS 13.1` it's possible to check the BT permission without allocating `CBManager`. Which is a huge advantage, as initializing `CBManager` will automatically trigger the system pop-up in case BT permission was not asked/given before.

```swift
func checkPermission() -> CBManagerAuthorization {
    if #available(iOS 13.1, *) {
        return checkPermissionBeforeCBManagerAllocation()
    } else {
        return checkPermissionLegacy()
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.1, *)
private func checkPermissionBeforeCBManagerAllocation() -> CBManagerAuthorization {
    CBCentralManager.authorization
}

private func checkPermissionLegacy() -> CBManagerAuthorization {
    let manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    return manager.authorization
}
```

The above is just an example for `iOS 13.x` versions and doesn't handle anything below that.

Comment: CBManager will not trigger a popup if permissions are denied, only if Bluetooth is powered off

Answer (score -1):

## Here is what I would use(Complete Solution for all iOS): **Swift 5**

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    var isiOSBluetoothOn = false
       
    @IBAction func onBluetoothButtonClicked(_ sender: Any){
        if (isiOSBluetoothOn) {
            let newVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "blevc")
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newVC!, animated: true)
        } else {
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                if (CBCentralManager().authorization != .allowedAlways) {   //System will automatically ask user to turn on iOS system Bluetooth if this returns false
                   openAppOrSystemSettingsAlert(title: "Bluetooth permission is currently disabled for the application. Enable Bluetooth from the application settings.", message: "")
                }
            } else {
                let appName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String
                openAppOrSystemSettingsAlert(title: "\"\(appName ?? "You Application Nam")\" would like to use Bluetooth for new connections", message: "You can allow new connections in Settings")
            }
        }
    }
                
    func openAppOrSystemSettingsAlert(title: String, message: String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController (title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default) { (_) -> Void in
            guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) else { return }
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                    print("Settings opened: \(success)") // Prints true
                })
            }
        }
        alertController.addAction(settingsAction)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension MainViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch central.state {
        case .poweredOn:
           isiOSBluetoothOn = true
            break
        case .poweredOff:
           isiOSBluetoothOn = false
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```