# Permissions: Allowed with the prompt, denied in settings, then still allowed when checking

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm working on a Xamarin.iOS app, and I'm trying to secure permissions. I already know that permission is asked only once, via the corresponding prompt.

But it seems that if, for instance, after the initial approval, I deny permission in the settings, say Bluetooth for example, CBCentralManager still returns **AlwaysAuthorized**...

```
Console.WriteLine($"BluetoothStatus [{CBCentralManager.Authorization}]");
```

Is it the default behavior and what can I do besides reinstalling the app to gain permission again?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Problem solved. I did not deny BLE at the app level but switch it off at the system level.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59283874/15186